# Approval field update

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I have 2 objects, i created  a approval process on 2nd object my requirement is on approval i need to update a field in first object,

Please let me know is it possible or not.

Comment: How are the two objects related?

Comment: now those two having lookup relation 1st object parent and second object child,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the approval process on Object 2, in the final approval step

- Use a Field Update to update some field `Foo`
- Define the Field Update to re-evaluate workflow rules - very important
- Use a Process Builder flow on Object2 that sees if Object2 has changed and has a new/expected value in field `Foo`. The action can then update the parent Object1.

You have to use Process Builder as Worklfow (except in rare cases like Case Comment->Case) can't update related records

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to have a master-detail relationship for a child to update fields on a parent object with a field-update workflow rule. [Cross-Object Field Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_cross_object_field_updates.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

You could come up with a work around where you set a field on the child object, and then use a trigger to set that value on the parent.